# delete() not does persist anymore in grails 2.4.1

Tags: grails, flush

While migrating a project from 1.3.7 to 2.4.1 I stumbled over several things. One of them is, that I found `obj.delete()` does not persist anymore in 2.4.1 unless I use `obj.delete(flush:true)`.

When I read the [Grails UserGuide](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/delete.html) where it says '... the instance being deleted immediately' I understand that the `flush:true` argument is an option to *force* persisting the object immediately instead of 'letting it persist when hibernate thinks its ok'.

But if `obj.delete()` never *really* deletes an object in terms of persiting the delete to the database, I don't get clue of having this possibility.

I testet this in a demo app with the following artifacts:

```
class Msg {
    String  text
}
```

and:

```
class MsgController {

    def index() {
        [list:Msg.list()]
    }

    def create() {
        def msg = new Msg(text:'hallo '+Msg.count())
        msg.save()
        redirect action:'index'
    }

    // this delete does NOT delete the object (hibernate creates no sql "delete from ..." command)
    def delete1() {
        def msg = Msg.get(params.id)
        msg.delete()
        flash.message = "msg [$msg.text] with id $msg.id deleted"
        redirect action:'index'
    }

    // this delete does delete the object
    def delete2() {
        def msg = Msg.get(params.id)
        msg.delete(flush:true)
        flash.message = "msg [$msg.text] with id $msg.id deleted using flush:true"
        redirect action:'index'
    }
}
```

and index.gsp:

```
<g:if test="${flash.message}">
    <p>${flash.message}</p>
</g:if>

<p>
    <g:link action="index">index</g:link>,
    <g:link action="create">create</g:link>
</p>

<p>
    <g:each in="${list}" var="msg">
        ${msg.id}: [${msg.text}], ***
        <g:link action="delete1" id="${msg.id}">delete()</g:link>
        <g:link action="delete2" id="${msg.id}">delete(flush:true)</g:link>
        <br>
    </g:each>
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Controllers created in 2.4 apps default to read-only transactions for performance reasons. This could be the reason you're seeing this, although I'm not 100% certain.

Nevertheless you should always perform a delete within a transaction so the best thing to do is either move the delete to a service and do it from there (recommended) or annotation your controller action with `grails.transaction.Transactional`, this will ensure the delete is committed at the end of controller execution.

Comment: Well thanks for making that clear. I think it would be nice to have a note in the user guide to tell the developer of this situation and whats the recommended way, which is: either use a service to delete or use Transactional annotation for the controller or use flush:true, as you said. Shall I raise a JIRA for that ?